# Multiple LEDs with reed switches for testing magnet placement

Tags: led, switching, parallel, magnet, reed-switch

[image: Simple circuit suggestion]

I'm adding MIDI to an old electric organ (saving the existing internals for dual operation).  I will be using reed switches and magnets at every key for action.

For testing magnet+reed positions I plan to use the attached circuit (or something).

I have a decorative chain of 10 warm white LEDs connected in parallel to a 3V (2xAA) battery pack that I will be salvaging and add the reed switches to.

Would the circuit work without destroying a single LED? Is there anything else I might have missed? Is there a simpler way to test the contacts?

---

The LEDs in question:
[image: Warm white LED]

Comment: You need to limit the current of the LEDs using a series resistor for each LED. Otherwise they'll glow very brightly for a brief moment, before they'll be destroyed.

Comment: I want to use all the LEDs after I have added the resistors. If I calculate the correct one (I don't know what the LEDs specs are) I get that one will get the right amount of power. I need to test the magnets and switches adacent as well, so I need to see at least 4-5 of them next to each other. Or do the resistors only limit the current so that even if I add one to every LED they will still get the forward voltage and work?

Comment: The LEDs are originally connected just like in the schematic but without the switches and they work well.

Comment: In some way or another you want to limit the current. It's usually either a current source if you want to regulate the brightness precisely, or a series resistor for a simple circuit with a voltage source.

Comment: The LED string probably has a single resistance for all the LEDs.  This won't work well if you turn LEDs on/off, since when all are off and then one turns on it will get 10x the current and be degraded/damaged.  Put a series resistor behind each LED to protect it and the reed switch.

Comment: White LEDs have a larger forward voltage than red ones, I suspect the battery can't produce enough voltage to damage them.

Comment: Ok, so I now got the chance to test this, Finbarr is correct. The whole thing works beautifully just like I drew the schematic, without any extra resistors. I assume the battery pack 'limits' its discharge, as the brightness of the LEDs doesn't visibly change when I add or remove LEDs in the circuit. 

I can't vote for answers yet... Thank you all very much.

Comment: @Mandibela If there was limiting on the battery pack it would be visibly different. They might have resistors built in with the LEDs; I've seen that before.

Comment: what does that circuit have to do with MIDI?

Comment: @jsotola I cannot use the in-circuit already existing switches for a secondary circuit, so nothing. This is a musical instrument specific question and MIDI wasn't tagged for clarity. ---- I have nothing else but the AA and a switch. The LEDs absolutely have no internal resistors in them, In this case the battery voltage is too low to fry the LEDs.

Comment: It's not a good idea to depend on the battery voltage to control the led brightness. Both the battery voltage and the LED forward voltage are temperature sensitive for example, so you're depending on nothing getting too warm and the batteries to always have a well defined voltage. Maybe it works, maybe it slowly burns out the LEDs.

Comment: Well, this is for testing some reed switches only, so not a long-term install or a project. I understand that using 1 ohm resistors at every LED would be appropriate, like this: [https://ledcalculator.net/#p=3&v=3.0&c=20&n=10&o=w](https://ledcalculator.net/#p=3&v=3.0&c=20&n=10&o=w)